# XSLT to pick last node element

Tags: xml, xslt

I know this is a very simple question but somehow my XSLT is not working. I've below XML from which I need to pick up the last index no. In this case it's 10. Can someone please provide the xsl. Thanks for your help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages xmlns="http://www.workday.com/wd-queue/17" returned-count="11" total-count="11">
    <message>
        <index>4</index>
        <uri>/ccx/wd-queue/queue_service_pxd/messages/4</uri>
        <size>1869</size>
        <uploaded>2016-06-14T14:14:47.000Z</uploaded>
        <content-type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</content-type>
    </message>
    <message>
        <index>5</index>
        <uri>/ccx/wd-queue/queue_service_pxd/messages/5</uri>
        <size>1820</size>
        <uploaded>2016-06-14T17:23:28.000Z</uploaded>
        <content-type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</content-type>
    </message>
    <message>
        <index>6</index>
        <uri>/ccx/wd-queue/queue_service_pxd/messages/6</uri>
        <size>1435</size>
        <uploaded>2016-06-14T17:45:45.000Z</uploaded>
        <content-type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</content-type>
    </message>
    <message>
        <index>7</index>
        <uri>/ccx/wd-queue/queue_service_pxd/messages/7</uri>
        <size>159031</size>
        <uploaded>2016-06-14T17:49:27.000Z</uploaded>
        <content-type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</content-type>
    </message>

    <message>
        <index>10</index>
        <uri>/ccx/wd-queue/queue_service_pxd/messages/10</uri>
        <size>1044</size>
        <uploaded>2016-06-14T18:07:31.000Z</uploaded>
        <content-type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</content-type>
    </message>

</messages>
```

XSLT I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.workday.com/wd-queue/17">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/message[last()]/index"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you add the XSLT you've tried and the desired output? Also, are you sure you need XSLT? A simple XPath could probably return what you're looking for.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/message[last()]/index"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: "*but somehow my XSLT is not working*" It's because your XML has a **namespace** which your XSLT does not respect. -- P.S. Please do not post code in comments - add your stylesheet to your question).

Comment: Sorry, I had that on my system but it still didn't work. Will post my XSL above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.workday.com/wd-queue/17">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:messages">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:message[last()]/ns1:index"/> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Done. Thanks again.